# XSLT for-each match problems

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a xhtml from which I need to extract data from. Using XMLSpy the xpath
`/html/body/div/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[5]/td/a/@name`
produces 24 items.

I am trying to get a simple list of these name attributes by doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <names>
            <xsl:for-each select="html/body/div/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[5]/td/a">
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </name>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </names>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This however produces an empty list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<names xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"/>
```

I tried several things like ./@name or prefixing the select with a / but nothing helps.

Can't figure out what I am missing. Any suggestions are welcome.

(I need to get data from different parts of the documents. That's why I am using a full xpath as the select. I don't control the generated xhtml so no chance to simplify things.)

Comment: Your XSLT seems to be correct. Is the XHTML created dynamically? Like with JavaScript?

Comment: The xhtml file is a static webpage, that is cleaned by using "html tidy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to explain how your (X)HTML looks and how it is parsed (as text/html or as XML) and where you execute the XSLT/XPath.

I see two problems:

- If it really is XHTML parsed as XML, then elements will be in the XHTML namespace, not in not namespace. So in XSLT 2 or 3 you need to add `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element to have any such path as you have shown select the input elements.
- If the input is parsed as text/html according to HTML rules then parser use to insert `tbody` elements to contain `tr` elements so you need to use e.g. `table/tbody/tr` anywhere you have `table/tr`.

Comment: Number one is the solution. Adding xpath-default-namespace did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a disagreement between XML spy and your xsl processor, you can investigate your XML by checking that the nodes are where you expect them to be :

You are expecting at least 1 node at the end of your xpath. You can check by output a count():

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <names>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(html/body/div/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[5]/td/a)">
        </names>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if the output is 0 then you have the wrong path. You can progressively walk up the tree to find where you are:

```
          <xsl:value-of select="count(html/body/div/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[5]/td)">
```

Once you find a node you can then construct the xpath yourself.

Or, you can just work it out - do you really have a table/table/table structure?

Comment: My xhtml is cleaned by "html tidy". So I know it is valid. And XMLSpy and online validation tools tell me the same.

In XMLSpy you can click a tag and a xpath is provided. But even if I build it by hand doing it step by step, I get the same xpath. So I know it is valid.

Even a count(html) or count(html/body) equals 0. I tried testing this in XMLSpy and using online tools. All with the same result. The count always returns 0, in every step I takeout, downto the html/body or html.

What is happening...???

Comment: I think you have a namespace in your xhtml that you need to include in your xsl. Include a sample xml in your question to show.